# SQL evaluating loop condition wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, while-loop, floating-point-precision

Part of one of my UDFs has a section that tries to find the number of decimal places after a float and returns the number multiplied up by powers of 10 such that it's an integer. Using 1.0005 as an example, here's the segment:

```
DECLARE @num FLOAT = 1.0005
DECLARE @exponent AS INT = 0

WHILE @num - FLOOR(@num) > 0.000001
BEGIN
SET @exponent += 1
SET @num *= 10
END
```

When I debug this in SSMS 2012, on the 'while' line if I evaluate `? CASE WHEN @num - FLOOR(@num) > 0.000001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` in the immediate window on its fourth iteration onwards I get 0 - however, the loop keeps running indefinitely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, to see what is going on ... @z doesn't change ...

```
DECLARE @num FLOAT = 1.0005
DECLARE @exponent AS INT = 0
declare @x float
declare @z float

WHILE @num - FLOOR(@num) > 0.000001
BEGIN
SET @exponent += 1
SET @num *= 10
set @x = FLOOR(@num)
set @z = @num - FLOOR(@num)
END
```

Comment: Indeed it doesn't - thanks, this helped me suss what I believe was the issue. @z remains slightly under 1, indicating that @num on each iteration is just less than an integer - putting this down to bad float precision (for some reason always inaccurate in the direction that breaks my code!), a `WHILE @num = FLOOR(ROUND(@num,10))` in place of the existing while clause fixed the issue.

Comment: *`WHILE @num <> FLOOR(ROUND(@num,10))` even!

Comment: cool!  wasn't sure what exactly you were looking for, so didn't suggest anything, but figured the debug would help...